# Zombie killer vehicle

Tags: zombies, vehicles

In a [*The Walking Dead*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(TV_series))™ world, what vehicle could be cobbled together, or used as is, to be:

- impervious to zombies - not get bogged, damaged or stopped by "herds" of them
- kill (severe head trauma is the only way) as many as possible?
- safe to operate (not require getting out of the vehicle to attack zombies)
- travel at a reasonable speed on roads when zombies aren't around

Comment: Is any fuel available? Big armored vehicles don't run on wishes....The show ignores the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A military or police [armored personal carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armoured_personnel_carrier).

These vehicles are specifically designed to withstand infantry attacks. When they can hold off an angry mob of protesters, they can hold off a horde of hungry zombies. It takes an anti-tank mine, shaped charge or RPG to crack them, and zombies usually don't know how to handle these properly.

They are also equipped with machine guns which can be operated from the inside. And when they run out of ammo, you can simply run the zombies over. APCs weight tens of tons and reach speeds of over 100 km/h. That should be enough to crush even the sturdiest zombie.

If you can choose, you might rather want to get one with wheels than one with tracks. They are usually more fuel-efficient, reach higher speed on-road and still have good off-road capabilities, they aren't as noisy and they are easier to operate when you know how to drive a normal car.

Comment: plus you can re-use the road, in case you want to travel the same route twice. With a tracked tank, roads don't last long.

Comment: @Burki That depends on the tracks. For most kinds of tanks there are two kinds of tracks. One kind for traveling roads (without damaging them) and one for off-road combat operations. You can swap them out in the field when you have the right tools available. In a zombie survival scenario, the road tracks would likely be enough. During my time in the German army I was stationed in a base with tanks. Tanks driving down roads was an everyday sight. There was nothing special about the roads in the base.

Answer (score 1):

## A tank

A tank is probably the only vehicle that will be able to not get stopped by some humanoid zombies that are in its way - it will simply drive through (or over) the horde.

You can also use it to attack the zombies if you happen to find some ammunition together with the vehicle in an abandoned military place.

The speed should be reasonable - it's not like you would have a lot of appointments during the zombie apocalypse and *zombies attacked me* is definitely a valid argument for why you are late.

Comment: I think that's overkill. Assuming you mean a battle tank like the Abrams or Leopard, both use much too much fuel, and their primary weapon is so massive it's next to useless. While you can kill a zombie with it, the ammo costs a fortune and you cannot carry very much of it. An armored (and armed) personnel carrier should work better. It's much lighter, uses a lot less fuel, and still has more than enough firepower to kill slow zombies.

Comment: Not to mention that you need to learn how to operate a tank while a personnel carrier is basically a large car (at least it appears so, please correct if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Any type of military vehicle. Think of a WWII Jeep and it's modifications. Almost every theatre had it versions with additional mods create for particular needs.  You had line remover with extra plating for running down Nazis. 
 Not to mention they are usually designed to be easily fixed by non experienced worker with a manual in one hand and wrench in other.

Same thing with modern Humvee, pick from 17 existing models, strap unpunchable tires to it, horizontal T section and off you go.

The plus of picking Humvee is that it can be filled on any gas station you encounter and it's not so gas guzzling like tanks or APC so you can have semi enjoyable speed with offroad mobility without the need to stop every 50 miles.